# usepackage {babel} and {chess} incompatibility

Tags: babel, chess

Have been using a document since time immemorial with `\usepackage{babel}` and `\usepackage{chess}`,
amongst many others which is why it took me hours to find the culprits. Out of the blue this evening
I get the error

```
"! Package babel Error: You are loading directly a language style.(babel) This syntax 
is deprecated and you must use(babel) \usepackage[language]{babel}."
```

Reading the current chess user guide continues to leave me clueless.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 15/5/2023
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:

%=======================
\usepackage[ngerman,french,spanish,italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{chess}

\begin{document}
Hi there. wtf!
\end{document}
```

Comment: well the chess.sty contains `\ifx\undefined\babel@core@loaded\input english.sty\fi`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and a file date pre-dating latex2e...

Comment: @ulrikefischer So, what do I do? Goodbye \usepackage{chess}?

Comment: I fixed your example so it does not generate spurious errors typesetting text in the preamble

Comment: "Out of the blue this evening"??? you get this error in any tex system for the last 10 years or so, nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chess.sty` is dated 1992, so naturally has no support for the new version, latex2e,  of latex which came out in 1993.

You need to give package authors time to update, expecting things to work after only 30 years seems impatient!

However you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 15/5/2023
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:

%=======================
\usepackage[ngerman,french,spanish,italian,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\babel@core@loaded\relax
\let\resetat\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{chess}

\begin{document}
Hi there. wtf!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did not mean to be unreasonable. Happy to wait for updates especially if there are fixes available like the one you are suggesting. My problem in these matters is and always has been that I refused to delve into D.Knuth's original TeX (which I am sure had been written for a Turing machine) and L.Lamport's what eventually became LaTeX2e as I felt it was enough of a challenge to come to grips with LaTeX3.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth given the package has been broken for 30 years I'd guess it is unlikely an update is comming soon.

Comment: I am resigned to doing without it.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth if you got it working before then you can presumably carry on doing the same, as I show here, but I'm sure there are newer packages available that have been designed to work with latex.

Comment: xskak seems to be the way to go.